# JS object and array selection and manipulation

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

When I get ajax data, it is an array:

```
[
  {"ID"  :"1",
   "Last":"SMITH",
  },
  {"ID"  :"2",
   "Last":"DOE",
  },
]
```

I am trying to save it into another array variable so that more ajax data can be added for future usage:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(ajax_data);
```

However, the ajax array is added into another array:

```
[
 [
  {"ID"  :"1",
   "Last":"SMITH",
  },
  {"ID"  :"2",
   "Last":"DOE",
  },
 ]
]
```

So here are my questions:

1. What do you guys suggest so that there is only one array with multiple ajax array addition? In other words, how I remove the extra `[]` syntax?
2. Each object will have multiple keys. I want to use "`ID`" as the primary key to find which object to work with. How do I search and select the correct object?

**FOR INDEXING:**

Below is a general array structure that I will be having which has `ID` and `post_id` as two keys, but can have other keys (values are copied and pasted for this demonstration). The number of objects can be up to 100.

This is ajax data and will be `concat` into an array.

[image]

As @jfriend00 pointed out, indexing it by ID can be inefficient. What would be a good way of indexing a large array by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you guys suggest so that there is only one array with multiple
>   ajax array addition? In other words, how I remove the extra [] syntax?

You need to use one of the methods that adds multiple elements to the array rather than adds the array itself (see options below).

To add onto an existing array, you can use `.push()` or `.splice()`.  You can also use `.concat()`, but it returns a new array which you would have to assign back to the prior variable:

```
var arr = [];

var newData = [
  {"ID"  :"1",
   "Last":"SMITH",
  },
  {"ID"  :"2",
   "Last":"DOE",
  },
];

// add newData onto arr using .push()
arr.push.apply(arr, newData);

// add newData onto arr using .concat()
// remember that .concat() returns a new array
arr = arr.concat(newData);
```

Using `.splice()` is a bit more involved and you would probably only do this if you were trying to replace elements.

```
  // put first two `.splice()` arguments onto front of the array
  newData.unshift(arr.length, 0);
  arr.splice.apply(arr, newData);
```

> Each object will have multiple keys. I want to use "ID" as the primary
>   key to find which object to work with. How do I search and select the
>   correct object?

If you want to be able to index by ID, then an array is not a very efficient structure.  You would have to search every object in the array to find those with a matching ID.  You could either create a separate index by ID or change the way you store your data.  How exactly to change how you store your data depends upon how you need to access it, whether there are multiple objects with the same keys, whether objects have more than one key, etc...  You'd have to specify a lot more detail on your needs for us to make a good recommendation.

For just 100 entries, you can easily do a brute force search:

```
function findById(array, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].ID === id) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you want to index them and all IDs are unique and order is not relevant, then instead of an array, just store in an object:

```
 var data = {};

 // add new data to our storage
 newData.forEach(function(item) {
     data[item.ID] = item;
 });
```

Then, to access by ID:

```
 var item = data[id];
```

---

In ES6 (or via transpiling or with a polyfill), you can also use a `Map` object.

```
 var data = new Map();

 // add new data to our storage
 newData.forEach(function(item) {
     data.set(item.ID, item);
 });
```

Then, to access by ID:

```
 var item = data.get(id);
```

An advantage of a `Map` object over using a regular JS object is that your id can be any data type (including another object).  When using a plain JS object, it has to be coerced to a unique string.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am curious about the indexing by ID. What would you suggest? Thank you

Comment: @steveKim - I added some info on that to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added a portion at the bottom of the question to include that image. There will be about 100 objects with multiple keys. I need an efficient way to search the object by ID. You mentioned about the separate index. How would that work?

Comment: @steveKim - The data you added to your question is all the same IDs.  I don't understand how you want to access it.  Are those all supposed to be collapsed to one object in one array entry because they're all identical or are they all supposed to be stored separately and, if stored separately, how do you want an index to work.  Still don't understand what problem you're' trying to solve.  If there's only 100, you can just brute force search the array and match.  100 is nothing for today's CPU.  Just create a function that searches and gets you what you want.

Comment: The data was copied (I got lazy lol). But it will all have different values.

Comment: @steveKim - I added a couple ideas.

Comment: Thank you! I am using the object method. Appreciate it! =)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve both problems if you save the data in an object, using `ID` as the keys. Initialize the variable as an empty object:

```
var saved_data = {};
```

Then in your AJAX callback function add the new objects to it:

```
ajax_data.forEach(function(object) {
    saved_data[object.ID] = object;
});
```

Now you can use `saved_data["1"].Last` to access a specific object.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you guys suggest so that there is only one array with multiple ajax array addition? In other words, how I remove the extra [] syntax?

You'll want to use `concat()` instead of `push()`:

`concat` creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument, the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the argument itself (if the argument is not an array).

```
var array1 = [
  {"ID"  :"1",
   "Last":"SMITH",
  },
  {"ID"  :"2",
   "Last":"DOE",
  },
];

var newArray = array1.concat(array2);
```

> Each object will have multiple keys. I want to use "ID" as the primary key to find which object to work with. How do I search and select the correct object?

If you want to retrieve based on `ID`:

```
var found;
var ID = "2";
newArray.some(function (obj) {
  if (obj.ID === ID) {
    found = obj;
    return true;
  }
});
```

`found` will be: `Object {ID: "4", Last: "DOE"}`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will definitely use `concat` for additional ajax array. However the issue is the very first ajax array. It needs to be saved into an array and it ends up being double bracket: "[[ ]]" instead of one. (In other words, I get the array from ajax, and it needs to be saved into another array, ending up double bracket which is not desirable).

Comment: @steveKim That shouldn't happen if you use `concat` the first time, too.